Does Play Asset Delivery support versioning?
My game uses install-time asset packs and they're huge (over 3gb) so I don't want them downloaded every time the app is updated. Is there a way to do this, perhaps with a "version=" property in the 'assetPack' section of the asset pack's build.gradle file?
// Asset pack gradle file
plugins {
    id 'com.android.asset-pack'
}
 
assetPack {
    packName = "play_assets1"
    version = 1.0 <-- Does something like this exist?
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "install-time"
    }
}

